# unable to create a python function app in azure function runtime v1

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am working on creating a function app using the v1 runtime, I was able to create the function app using python in the v1 environment till sep 24th, but since then I am not able to see the python option, the official documentation says it supports python v1 though experimental.

Referring to this guide:

> https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/blob/master/docs/create-function-app-in-azure-portal.md

has python runtime been taken off completely in the v1 environment[image]

I do not see the experimental language support anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's an issue, tracked by https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-ux/issues/3231. Until the fix is deployed, manually delete the `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME` App Setting from your app, and refresh the portal.