# Powershell / Azure Functions - Do not run at all

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

Got a Azure Function (Queue) with a powershell script from git source. When I click run nothing happens, se picture below!

I've set up everything on a new tenant, but one strange thing. I did not find experminental language option (powershell) when creating the Azure Functions. So I choose to get it from a source (git). I've also activated 64-bit and Managed service identity (I'm later going to use the key vault)

[image]

Comment: For the missing experimental option, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52523383/unable-to-create-a-python-function-app-in-azure-function-runtime-v1 for workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed "dotnet" from Application Settings. Think this get's in by default after they changed the settings when creating a new Azure Functions

[image]